# Yeoman install and collaboration (over git for instance)

Tags: git, dependencies, collaboration, yeoman, bower

I am starting my first serious project using yeoman and I hit an issue that I couldn't figure out from the doc.

My new webapp uses bootstrap-js and lodash as base javascript, so I did `yeoman install ...` for these two libraries. This seems to have cloned the whole github repository of both libraries (plus jquery) to two `components` directory, one at the root of the app, and one in the `app` directory.

Now, I want to commit this to my git repository. Clearly, there is no point in putting the whole repositories of the dependent libraries in my repository. At worst, I could put just the min.js files that are withing the components directory. But I guess the best would be to just add a file listing the dependencies, and having the other coders install the dependencies on their machine using yeoman.

Is there a way to do that? There seem to be a `package.json` which might be the place to put that, but what would be the format? The doc mentions `components.json` from Bower, but it's not clear either how this could be used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice at the moment is to create a [component.json](https://github.com/twitter/bower#defining-a-package) file with your dependencies and then gitignore the components folders, or you can just include the components folders.

We're working on getting a [.bowerignore](https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/88) type of file so that components only include what's actually needed.

*For the double components folder question, see [Why does bower install packages twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676313/64949)*

Comment: ok, but what would someone cloning the repository would have to do to get the missing components? `yeoman update`?

Comment: how do i find package names and versions to place in component.json? for instance I am using the latest require, lodash and jquery

Comment: Use `bower install --save` to install and add the component to component.json.